# What does this crash log means? Unable to symbolize

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-reports, flurry

Can you please help me with below crash log, it comes over my iPad application on Flurry analytics. I am not able to symbolize this log so posting here.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         MyApp [180]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/97D3AAB9-74C2-4389-A4BF-771D18DC11D3/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      com.bentley.MyApp
Version:         058
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Exception Type:  SIGBUS
Exception Codes: BUS_ADRALN at 0xb8c500
Crashed Thread:  6

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f1c808 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e5de03 <redacted> + 38

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f2fc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f96a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f2fc70 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f96a98 _start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f1ca58 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2ed9689b <redacted> + 154
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2ed94fc1 <redacted> + 784
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2ecfff0f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2ecffcf3 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
5   Foundation                          0x2f73f087 +[NSURLConnection _resourceLoadLoop:] + 318
6   Foundation                          0x2f7b4a5f <redacted> + 1062
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f98919 <redacted> + 140
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f9888b __pthread_start + 102
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f96aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f2f434 ___select + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f98919 <redacted> + 140
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f9888b __pthread_start + 102
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x39f96aa4 _thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39f2f974 ___sigsuspend_nocancel + 12
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39e5b647 <redacted> + 34

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   ???                                 0x00b8c500 0x0 + 0

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    pc: 0x00b8c500     r7: 0x00b8ca00     sp: 0x06ea91ec     r0: 0x00000000 
    r1: 0x00001000     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0x16d3e930     r4: 0x00b8c500 
    r5: 0x00000008     r6: 0x00000001     r8: 0x00000000     r9: 0x00000000 
   r10: 0x3bf08c30    r11: 0x00b89000     ip: 0x16d3ea88     lr: 0x39f06543 
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

What does this Crash log means?

Comment: Why can't you symbolicate. Do you really expect us to be able to tell you what was happening in your application based on this? :/

Comment: No you can also guide me how to symbolicate flurry crash logs.

Comment: There are dozens of questions and answers about how symbolication can be done. Use the search feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

> The SIGBUS signal is sent to a process when it causes a bus error. The conditions that lead to the signal being raised are, for example, incorrect memory access alignment or non-existent physical address.

You are having a major memory management issue. The error also caused the stack trace to be corrupt so the crashed thread doesn't show anything useful.

All you can do is: search for memory leaks (ARC doesn't solve all this magically for all possible scenarios!), use static analyzer, use instruments.

Comment: Thanks Kerni, this is useful info for start-up.

Comment: The crash happened in thread 0 (main thread). But the crash was too severe for the crash reporting SDK to recover any useful information (stack trace).

Comment: When I build and run over device, I am not able to reproduce any such crashes. Also I have tried with Enterprise build to repro the same but no luck. So stuck with the cause finding. :/

Comment: These kind of bugs are never easy to find and it doesn't matter how you sign them. For such crashes a crash report will also never ever be able to tell you where exactly the bug is. Use the tools I mentioned in the answer, they might be able to give a hint.

Comment: Please find updated crash log. It happens again over Flurry logs, but this time on Thread 6. Is it mean that this is not on main thread, rather on some child thread?

Comment: Also, does force quit cause such crashes (I don't know so asking)? If not, then what could be the possible areas to check, as we are not able to reproduce this at our end